# Dynamically Loading a pre-compiled class without reflection

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

In my specific case I'd like to load a class in runtime where: I have the class (and its definition) at compile time but I only find out the **location** of its containing jar at runtime. Somewhat reversed from the classic classloading case where the **name** of the class is only known at runtime.

Let's assume the class to load is *org/animals/Cat.class* and it is one class out of many in *animals.jar*. When I compile my program, animals.jar is in my compile time class path, because I know where it is, e.g:
`javac -cp <path to>/animals.jar Something.java`

I can import it, reference it, and compile my program *Something.java*

```
import org.animals.Cat;

    ...
    Cat c = new Cat();
    c.makesound();
```

Now I deploy the program to a production system, where the location of animals.jar and other libraries is only known at runtime. If I knew the location, I could have used

```
java -cp <path to>/animals.jar Something
```

But I only find it out at runtime. I was hoping that I can use a URLClassLoader to make it work. Assuming the passed in runtime path to jar is stored under 'location', I can create a classloader that loads it:

```
URL url = new File(location + "/animals.jar").toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
URLClassLoader cLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

And then just use Cat in my program, as compiled, without having to resort
to reflection. For example, this is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
Class clazz = cLoader.loadClass("org.animals.Cat")
Object o = clazz.newInstance();
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("makesound", ...);
```

Is this indeed doable without reflection? can I cash on the benefit of knowing the class at compile time? or must I use reflection as in above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Cat` class is known to implement, say, some `Animal` interface then you can do `Animal a = (Animal)o` and start invoking `Animal` methods on `a` without any use of reflection.